# How many servers are listening during a Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am going through the configuration of my cluster and I would like to reinforce security by minimizing how many machines actually can access http protocols

So my question is: when doing a Spark streaming (say over a twitter feed), is the driver the only server listening to the stream and then re-distributing the data to the executors as an RDD, or is every executor listening to the stream?

Comment: Randomly chosen worker node will be receiving the stream.

Comment: @vanekjar, do you have the source doc? Is there any way to force a specific server to receive the stream?

Comment: could you add the code how you setup your job?

Comment: It's from the Spark Streaming official documentation: `each input DStream creates a single receiver (running on a worker machine) that receives a single stream of data` [https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark Streaming will issue long-running tasks for each receiver created during the Spark Streaming configuration. Those receivers are allocated on some node on the cluster.

If you want to specify the host where each receiver is instantiated, you will have to extend the Receiver implementation and implement

```
def preferredLocation: Option[String]
```